# CSS - Place Validation Message Below Element - MVC 3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

All,

I need to have any input validation messages display below the element instead of next to it. The base CSS file puts a margin-bottom = 19px on the `<input />` element so I need to offset this because if I don't the message gets inserted 19px below the input element.

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/L28E7/2/

ASP.NET is generating all of the HTML so I am hamstrung somewhat in terms of what I can do.
I can access the  .field-validation-error class and override it so that's what I did.

My CSS works (In FireFox at least) and produces the following:

[image]

I had to use negative margin-top to get the message right under the element, which I am not happy with.

How can I improve this?

Thank you!

**The CSS**

```
div .field-validation-error {
    color: #C1372A !important;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    margin-top: -19px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div>
<label for="NewClub.NewClubName">Name your club!!!</label>
<span class="required">*</span>
</div>
<input type="text" value="" name="NewClub.NewClubName" id="NewClub_NewClubName" data-val-required="Please provide your club with a name." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="NewClub.NewClubName"></span>
```

Comment: wondering how the css worked for you, The span class is what you need to work on for the error message, but you are assigning css to DIV.

Answer (score 0):

if this is how your HTML looks after the creating of inline error message

```
<input type="text" value="" name="NewClub.NewClubName" id="NewClub_NewClubName" data-val-required="Please provide your club with a name." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="NewClub.NewClubName">heloo hell</span>
```

Then use the below css. This will automatically put your message below the text box

```
.field-validation-error {
   color: #C1372A !important;
   display: block;
   font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/L28E7/

Comment: The problem is actually a margin-bottom value assigned to all inputs. See http://jsfiddle.net/L28E7/2/